# Why does res.sendFile path need the same directory as in the express.static?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I spent a long time on my app confused why the wrong index.html file was showing and I found the solution but I don't understand why.

I have two html files:
One in a `public` directory and another in a `dist` directory

In my Express routes I originally wrote:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

/* ...some express routes... */

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});
```

I thought I could statically server files in the `public` directory (like css and images) but when no other route was specified, I could load the `index.html` file in `dist`.

However when I ran my app I would see the `index.thml` file from `public`. This wasn't what I wanted. So i changed the top line from "public" to "dist" like this:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));`

Any now my app loads the correct index.html.

What's going on here? Did Express default to "public" even though I listed "dist" in res.sendFile? Why is this the solution?

Thanks for helping me understand!

Comment: Remember that routes are search in the order you configure them.  So, if you have an `index.html` in the `public` directory and you request `/index.html`, then the `express.static()` middleware will find and serve that file, even if you later have another route that would also serve that file.  You probably also need to make sure you aren't getting  occasionally fooled by browser caching, particuclarly if you have the same filename in multiple places.

Comment: @jfriend00 Can I serve both public and dist with `express.static()`? If I served both directories, would the route then serve the index.html in dist? What confuses me is that if I have `path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html')` i'd expect it to look in dist and not pubic.

Comment: Yes, you can serve both directories with `express.static()`.  They will be searched in the order you register the middleware.  You will probably want to make sure there are no duplicate filenames between the two directories.